# Visibility panel - can not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, panel

I have very strange situation: I have asp:panel in my aspx code, in code behind I try to set up visibility of it. This is code

```
divDiscountCodeCongratulation.Visible = true;
```

code in aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="pan1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel class="sbox-gratulacje" ID="divDiscountCodeCongratulation" runat="server" >
        <asp:Literal ID="LitDiscountCodeCongratulation" runat="server" Text="Gratulacje "></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal ID="litDiscountInfoFromCode" runat="server"></asp:Literal>       
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDiscountCodeCancel" runat="server" Text="Cofnij" OnClick="btnDiscountCodeCancel_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

I put breakpoint on this line, just after it I have still false value (default value). The same situation is when I try to set it in Immediate Window.

Does anyone know why this happen??

---

All parents of "divDiscountCodeCongratulation" have to have set Visibility to true.

Comment: Do you have any `css` styles with the class ***sbox-gratulacje***??

Comment: _When_ do you set the property? Provide context.

Comment: Page_Load(object ...) {}

Comment: @Jacek, the default value for Visible property is `true` - so you must setting it to `false` somewhere - so where is that happening?

Comment: The Panel itself could be "invisible" if it has no style and its content ha visible = false. Please provide more code-behind and the CSS Style.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS. If *server-side* Visible property is set to False then ASP.NET simple will not render the control - there will be no HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that **pan1** is visible. If it is invisible that is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I used your aspx code and in my code behind page_load i just put :
divDiscountCodeCongratulation.Visible = false;

and panel visibility is set to false i.e. divDiscountCodeCongratulation is not visible.

> Default value of Panel visibility is True not False, as you mentioned that default value is False.You can check that if visibility of panel is being set in cssclass
>   *sbox-gratulacje* or not.

***Also,check below example that will hide panel on linkbutton1 click and show panel on  linkbutton2 click***

**ASPX code :**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton1</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton
    ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton2_Click">LinkButton2</asp:LinkButton>
```

Master Panel
    
    Child Panel

**Code Behind :** 
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divDiscountCodeCongratulation.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divDiscountCodeCongratulation.Visible = true;
    }